# New Xrandr mode not showing - Dell Inc. Vostro 5568

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 onto a Dell Inc. Vostro 5568 with Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) and the max resolution I have available is 1366x768 for the native display.

I've attempted to add both 1920x1080 and 1600x900 but neither were successful.

the output for xrandr is;

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1360x768      59.80*+
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

Output for cvt 1600 900 is

```
1600x900 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.44M9) hsync: 55.99 kHz; pclk: 118.25 MHz
Modeline "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
```

So I ran the following commands with no errors but the resolution doesn't appear in the settings menu

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "1600x900_60.00"
```

I also added the lines to gedit ~/.profile with no effect, I've tried xrandr --fb 1600x900 with no errors

The only place I've gotten an error is with xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode "1600x900_60.00" which produced the following error;

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  21 (RRSetCrtcConfig)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
```

Comment: If the panel's native resolution is 1366x768 then that's the one that should be used, period. In any case you can't never go higher that the maximum resolution (maximum = native), only lower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that find this in the future, it appears it is not possible to override however I have worked around the issue by installing [Tweaks](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/) and using Scaling Factor to get the appearance of a higher resolution.